# javascript create object dynanically by variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

I want to create an object based on the value of a variable. I hope the following code can explain better what I want:

```
$('.tariffCostState').each(function(){
        var tariffCostObj = $(this).data('tariff-code-name');

/*
    How do I set the value of tariffCostObj as an object ?

[EDIT]
        Imagine that var tariffCostObj='abc';
        I want that abc becomes an object: abc={}
*/
        var testObj={};

        var tariffCostsInput=$(this).find('input.m2m-tariff-costs-input');

        for(var j= 0, inputLen = tariffCostsInput.length; j<inputLen; j++){
            var tariffCostsInputId = $(this).find('input.m2m-tariff-costs-input').eq(j).attr('id');
            var tariffCostsInputValue= $(this).find('input.m2m-tariff-costs-input').eq(j).val();

            testObj[tariffCostsInputId]=tariffCostsInputValue;

            //The goal is to have:
            abc[tariffCostsInputId]=tariffCostsInputValue;



        }
        console.log(testObj);

    });
```

Instead of an object called `testObj` I want the value of `tariffCostObj` (abc, ... ) The testeObj is just an example

Thanks

Comment: possibly like this you mean? `{valueOftariffCostObj :{....}}`

Comment: Please show outline  of expected resultant object. Not really clear what objective is

Comment: Bear in mind that the object you set in there is only visible within the `.each()`. Would you want to be able to access it outside of each as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear but i think you want to do this:

```
var testObj={};
$('.tariffCostState').each(function(){

    var tariffCostObj = $(this).data('tariff-code-name');

    if( 'undefined' === typeof testObj[ tariffCostObj ] ) 
         testObj[ tariffCostObj ] = {};

/*
How do I set the value of tariffCostObj as an object ?
*/


    var tariffCostsInput=$(this).find('input.m2m-tariff-costs-input');

    for(var j= 0, inputLen = tariffCostsInput.length; j<inputLen; j++){
        var tariffCostsInputId = $(this).find('input.m2m-tariff-costs-input').eq(j).attr('id');
        var tariffCostsInputValue= $(this).find('input.m2m-tariff-costs-input').eq(j).val();

       testObj[ tariffCostObj ][tariffCostsInputId]=tariffCostsInputValue;


    }
    console.log(testObj);

});
```

Comment: it's on a good way. But it creates an empty object inside the main object. All the properties should be inside the dynamic object. I just edit the post for a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
var someObjName = "myObj";
var someObjPropName = "myProp";
var someObjPropValue = "myVal";

window[someObjName] = {};
window[someObjName][someObjPropName] = someObjPropValue;
```

Now you have an object named myObj with a property and a value in it.